# Java: How can I find the caller of a method at compilation time?

Tags: java, reflection, methods, compilation, runtime

I have a Java problem for which I can't find an answer: I have a class **A** containing a method **a()** that should only be called from a class extending class **B**. For the moment, the best solution I could find is the one below:

```
Class callerClass = Reflection.getCallerClass(2);
if (!B.class.isAssignableFrom(callerClass))
    throw new InvalidMethodCallException("A.a", B.class.getName(), callerClass.getName());
```

With `InvalidMethodCallException` being an exception of my own.

However, I am not completely satisfied with my solution because of the fact that the call is made at runtime. Instead, I would want to declare in **`a()`** that only **`B`** should have access to it, but make this is checked at compilation time, since reflection is a costly process.

Do you know a proper way to do so ?

Thank you for your help.

*Edit: Additional information*

An easier example is that I don't want the user to call the method `connect(port1, port2)` in class `Edge`, but instead to call the method `addEdge(edge, port1, port2)` from the `Graph` class, because the graph also has to remember what edges if has inside.

Here is my code from class `Graph`:

```
        public void addEdge (Edge edge, Port firstPort, Port secondPort)
            throws DuplicateEdgeInGraphException, AttachedNodeNotInGraphException, GraphDescriptionModelException
        {

            // Must not appear in the graph
            if (this.edges.contains(edge))
                throw new DuplicateEdgeInGraphException(edge);

            // The nodes attached to the ports must be in the graph
            if (!this.nodes.contains(firstPort.getNode()))
                throw new AttachedNodeNotInGraphException(firstPort);
            if (!this.nodes.contains(secondPort.getNode()))
                throw new AttachedNodeNotInGraphException(secondPort);

            // We connect the edge and add it
            edge.connect(firstPort, secondPort);
            this.edges.add(edge);

        }
```

And from class `Edge`:

```
        public void connect (Port portOne, Port portTwo)
            throws InvalidMethodCallException, WrongPortsDirectionsException, WrongPortsSizesException, GraphDescriptionModelException
        {

            // We check the reserved method call
            Class callerClass = Reflection.getCallerClass(2);
            if (!Graph.class.isAssignableFrom(callerClass))
                throw new InvalidMethodCallException("Edge.connect", Graph.class.getName(), callerClass.getName());

            // We check the directions of the ports
            if ((portOne.isInputPort() && !portOne.isInputOutputPort() && !portTwo.isOutputPort())
            || (portTwo.isInputPort() && !portTwo.isInputOutputPort() && !portOne.isOutputPort())
            || (portOne.isOutputPort() && !portOne.isInputOutputPort() && !portTwo.isInputPort())
            || (portTwo.isOutputPort() && !portTwo.isInputOutputPort() && !portOne.isInputPort()))
                throw new WrongPortsDirectionsException(portOne, portTwo);

            // We check the sizes of the ports
            if ((portOne.isInputPort() && !portOne.isInputOutputPort() && portOne.getSize() < portTwo.getSize())
            || (portTwo.isInputPort() && !portTwo.isInputOutputPort() && portTwo.getSize() < portOne.getSize())
            || (portOne.isOutputPort() && !portOne.isInputOutputPort() && portOne.getSize() > portTwo.getSize())
            || (portTwo.isOutputPort() && !portTwo.isInputOutputPort() && portTwo.getSize() > portOne.getSize())
            || (portOne.isInputOutputPort() && portTwo.isInputOutputPort() && portOne.getSize() != portTwo.getSize()))
                throw new WrongPortsSizesException(portOne, portTwo);

            // We avoid similar edges
            for (Edge portOneEdge : portOne.getConnectedEdges())
                if (portOneEdge.getOppositePort(portOne).equals(portTwo))
                    throw new SimilarEdgeAlreadyExistsException(portOneEdge);

            // Ports' attributes
            portOne.getConnectedEdges().add(this);
            portTwo.getConnectedEdges().add(this);

            // Attributes
            this.portOne = portOne;
            this.portTwo = portTwo;

        }
```

Hope this helps understanding the problem.

*Edit: Thanks to everyone!*

Comment: Not an answer: try to rethink your design to remove that cross-dependency.

Comment: Move the method into the desired class `A`, and make it protected. Then only classes derived from `A` will be able to call it.

Comment: In fact, I am working on a graph theory library, and I want the user to use the **connect()** method from my **Edge** class instead of manipulating the **Ports** attached to the **Nodes** (that also have a **connect()** method), because operations need to be performed on the edge and on the two target ports. So there is no point in inheritance and protected methods here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at [Annotation Processing Tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/apt/). It allows you to make compile time annotations and produce warnings/errors at the time code is compiled.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at it. It seems to be what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a clean way to do this. Please consider an alternative design.

If you want class A only serves class B and its child classes, define class A as an inner class of B and give it protected access modifier.

Comment: The problem is that class A has other purposes than serving class B (see my answer in the previous message).

By the way, do you think it would be a better solution to let my **Edge** class handle all the communication process and add itself to the list of connected edges from class **Port** instead of leaving the port handling its own representation?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am not 100% understand the scenario. Maybe you can post some of your code? What I think is that if you define a method in a class, it means it is the unique behavior of the class. You can call it to perform tasks about this object, but it is not good to call it to perform a task on other classes (if I understand it correct). In your case, if you want all your Ports, Nodes and Edge to perform a common behavior, I will consider making connect() a Utility method inside a Utility class.